# Magento 2.3.3 stopped working. CMS Blocks the with same identifiers doesn't work

Tags: magento2

We have been using **CMS blocks** with the same **identifiers** (see image), to be able to use child themes and include the these CMS blocks to several store views.

[image: CMS Block Identifier]

After a upgrade to Magento 2.3.3 that's not working anymore.

[image: Error]

Anyone have a solution for this or can shed some light?

Thanks,

**EDIT**

Found This at GitHub:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4831

Comment: Please use unique `identifiers` and check it. It will work.

Comment: I really want continue using identifiers with the same names, as I have done in earlier versions of Magento. It's (was) a great feature when using a lot of child themes in a multistore setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could replicate the same issue in my m2 local instance and identified the reason that you had this issue, also provided below a quick fix for this.

**Cause of the issue**

There's a difference in code between 2.3.3. and 2.2.x versions in CMS Block ResourceModel Class ***vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/ResourceModel/Block.php*** in the method
**getIsUniqueBlockToStores**

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.3/app/code/Magento/Cms/Model/ResourceModel/Block.php

In this method, they check for uniqueness of the block id to selected store(s). In your case, it fails because its not unique as you have same id for both store-view and all store views.

In the recent Magento 2.3.x. version it checks the database table `cms_block_store` to confirm whether the static block exists, **only if its a default store**.

***Whereas in the prior versions it does check the `cms_block_store` irrespective of the store scope of the block saved.***

**A quick fix** (dont make this change, find the module given below under solution and install this in your store to fix your issue.)

removed the condition to confirm whether its a default store to add the WHERE condition to check the `cms_block_store` always, as it was before, in CMS Block Resource Model.

> vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/ResourceModel/Block.php

```
/**
     * Check for unique of identifier of block to selected store(s).
     *
     * @param AbstractModel $object
     * @return bool
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.BooleanGetMethodName)
     */
    public function getIsUniqueBlockToStores(AbstractModel $object)
    {
        $entityMetadata = $this->metadataPool->getMetadata(BlockInterface::class);
        $linkField = $entityMetadata->getLinkField();
        $stores = (array)$object->getData('store_id');
        $isDefaultStore = $this->_storeManager->isSingleStoreMode()
            || array_search(Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID, $stores) !== false;

         // commented out the if condition below to include the default store id 0 when we check the uniqueness of the block

        //if (!$isDefaultStore) {
            //$stores[] = Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID;
        //}

        $select = $this->getConnection()->select()
            ->from(['cb' => $this->getMainTable()])
            ->join(
                ['cbs' => $this->getTable('cms_block_store')],
                'cb.' . $linkField . ' = cbs.' . $linkField,
                []
            )
            ->where('cb.identifier = ?  ', $object->getData('identifier'));

        // commented out the if condition below to check the `cms_block_Store` tale always   
        //if (!$isDefaultStore) {
            $select->where('cbs.store_id IN (?)', $stores);
        //}


        if ($object->getId()) {
            $select->where('cb.' . $entityMetadata->getIdentifierField() . ' <> ?', $object->getId());
        }
        if ($this->getConnection()->fetchRow($select)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**Solution** (Create and Enable this Module)

Create the following directories and files as given below

**File**

> app/code/StackExchange/Override/Model/ResourceModel/Block.php

**Code**

```
<?php

/* @author Jerome Dennis <haijerome@gmail.com> */ 

namespace StackExchange\Override\Model\ResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

/**
 * CMS block model
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Block extends \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block
{
    /**
     * Check for unique of identifier of block to selected store(s).
     *
     * @param AbstractModel $object
     * @return bool
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.BooleanGetMethodName)
     */
    public function getIsUniqueBlockToStores(AbstractModel $object)
    {
        $entityMetadata = $this->metadataPool->getMetadata(BlockInterface::class);
        $linkField = $entityMetadata->getLinkField();

        $stores = (array)$object->getData('store_id');
        $isDefaultStore = $this->_storeManager->isSingleStoreMode()
            || array_search(Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID, $stores) !== false;

         // commented out the if condition below to include the default store id 0 when we check the uniqueness of the block

        //if (!$isDefaultStore) {
            //$stores[] = Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID;
        //}

        $select = $this->getConnection()->select()
            ->from(['cb' => $this->getMainTable()])
            ->join(
                ['cbs' => $this->getTable('cms_block_store')],
                'cb.' . $linkField . ' = cbs.' . $linkField,
                []
            )
            ->where('cb.identifier = ?  ', $object->getData('identifier'));

            $select->where('cbs.store_id IN (?)', $stores);

        if ($object->getId()) {
            $select->where('cb.' . $entityMetadata->getIdentifierField() . ' <> ?', $object->getId());
        }

        if ($this->getConnection()->fetchRow($select)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**File**

> app/code/StackExchange/Override/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block" type="StackExchange\Override\Model\ResourceModel\Block" />
</config>
```

**File**

> app/code/StackExchange/Override/etc/module.xml

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 *   StackExchange_Override
 *   Jerome Dennis <haijerome@gmail.com>
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="StackExchange_Override" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Cms"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**File**

> app/code/StackExchange/Override/registration.php

**Code**

```
<?php
/**
 *   StackExchange_Override
 *   Jerome Dennis <haijerome@gmail.com>
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'StackExchange_Override',
    __DIR__
);
```

I assume that you have a development / staging instance and you are on developer mode. (dont try this on production before you try this on development or staging server)

- enable the module (php bin/magento module:enable StackExchange_Override)
- register the module in the set up table (php bin/magento setup:upgrade)
- remove the generated files generated\code and regenrate (php bin/magento setup:di:compile)
- clean the cache types

This will certainly fix the issue that you face (tested and verified on my local instance). Thank You !

[image] [image]

Comment: I have tried your fix, and I can save the blocks in "All Store Views" now, that's great. But I can't save the blocks in specific "Store Views", they still show the error about the identifier properties. Am I missing something? Thanks,

Comment: Note that this is when editing already created CMS blocks in store views, not creating new ones (haven't tested that yet).

Comment: @Alldo you can find this modified code changes above in the file app/code/StackExchange/Override/Model/ResourceModel/Block.php which will allow you to edit and save the blocks assigned to specific store views and all store views. It also works fine for new blocks with same identifier. Basically the code above skips the validation of the uniqueness of the 'block identifier', which is justified in your case as per your business requirement and it also sounds logical to me.

Comment: Fantastic, works like a charm. Can't understand why they made these changes, do you @Haijerome?

Comment: @Alldo glad it helps you. BTW it seems they have ignored to evaluate different use cases like the store owner needs to keep the same identifier for all store views and store specific for their magento e-commerce store front. The validation of default store (all store views) is totally unnecessary in my opinion. Because if the Magento core developers felt that it's necessary then they would have made the cms block identifier as a unique field in the cms block tables. I also notice a difference in opinion between various contributors of this issue.

Comment: You should put this on GitHub! Thanks again for you help!

Answer (score 0):

The first block is set to store view "All Store Views".

Change this to a different store view and you can save the block.

Comment: But I want that block identifier name for "All Store Views", that's the point. Since upgrading Magento to version 2.3.3, that feature has stopped working.

Comment: You can use the same block identifier name. You can't use All Store Views and another store view for a block with the same identifier name.

Comment: No not right now, but I could before, that's the problem. Look at the image in the post, its a real image taken from the actual store, not an example what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the first block from the site mentioned in your screenshot.

Then create blocks with same identifier for all available stores and save.
Voila, now the site will have same identifier across all store views, hope this is enough?

Additionally, one thing to let you know is that same identifier cant be used if its set for "all store views" in a block. This is the default property of Magento and it should be. Otherwise, it wont make any sense i think. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update CMS block programmatically there is more elegant solution then rewriting **Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block::getIsUniqueBlockToStores**

All you need to do is to set right area before doing anything with block

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState
    ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;        
    $this->appState = $appState;
}

public function updateCmsBlock($block)
{
    
    $self = $this;
    try {
        $this->appState->emulateAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML, function () use ($self) {
            $additionalStores = ['2','4', '35']; //add to another stores
            $newTitle = 'A new title for block';

            $block->setData('store_id', $additionalStores);
            $block->setTitle($newTitle)
            $this->blockRepository->save($block);
        });
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
         //do something with exception
    }
    
    
 }
```